# Calling sort() on a vector that's a member of a class "No matching function for call to swap()"

Tags: c++, sorting, stl-algorithm

I have a class A declared as:

```
class A {
public:
    vector<int> vec;
};
```

Running the following code:

```
const A *a = new A();
sort(a->vec.begin(), a->vec.end());
```

gives me the error:

```
algorithm: No matching call to swap()
```

in Xcode.

Any clue as to why this is happening?

Comment: Are you perhaps running the sort call in a const function? It so it can't modify the vector.

Comment: The arguments are const. The sort is called inside a function "bool comp(const A* a, const A* b)" used as the comparator argument in sort(Iter::vector<A*>,Iter::vector<A*>,comp).

Comment: Since `a` is a const pointer you cannot mutate it or its members, so you can't call sort. Get rid of the const and it will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`const A *a` means "pointer to `const A`, and that means the object pointed at by `a` cannot be modified via `a`. `sort` modifies the elements of the iteration range passed to it. Since these elements are owned by the object pointed at by `a`, they cannot be modified via `a`.

So, you cannot call sort the vector `a->vec`. You need to find a different approach.